Use the flacards package to create single-sided flashcards
I am trying to create some flashcards using the flacards package. Ideally, I would like them to be single-sided, but this package doesn't seem to have an option to do this. Is there a (relatively) easy way I can accomplish this? An answer to this question (How to add space between flashcards boxes using latex flacards package?) seems to indicate that there is a way to do so using \setlength{\cardmargin}{\cardwidthspace}, but I do not understand how to set it up.
I'd like to either generate the cards without backs or somehow remove every other page in the document. I know there are pdf editors which can facilitate this, but it would be nice if I could just generate the document in one go.
\documentclass[frontgrid,backgrid,a4paper,11pt]{flacards}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\frhead}{\#1}
    \renewcommand{\frfoot}{noun}
    \card{class}{DataBase 3300\\Unit 1}
\end{document}

